# the error is exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace) . line 26 ---- def__init__(self, battery_size = 70):

Tags: python, python-3.x

I do not understand what is wrong in the 26th line - `def__init__(self, battery_size = 70):` - of this code. I'm facing the error an error
from `exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)`.

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return long_name.title()

    def read_odometer(self):
        print("This car has" + str(self.odometer_reading) + "miles on it.")

    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        if mileage >= self.odometer_readings:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
        else:
            print("You can't roll back an odometer!")

    def increment_odometer(self, miles):
        self.odometer_reading += miles


class Battery():
    def__init__(self, battery_size = 70):
        self.battery_size = battery_size
    def describe_battery(self):
        print("This car has a " + str(self.battery_size) + "-kWh battery." )

class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery_size = Battery()



my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2016)
print(my_tesla.get_descriptive_name())
my_tesla.describe_battery()
```

The output intended for this would be

```py
2016 Tesla Model S # from .get_descriptive_name()
This car has a 70-kWh battery. # from .describe_batttery()
```

Comment: You need a space between `def` and `__init__`...

Comment: my_tesla is instance of class ElectricCar in which there is no method describe_battery(): this method is inside class Battery

Comment: After I've fixed this typo the next error is that you call `describe_battery()` for an `ElectricCar` even though it's a method that only exists for `Battery`s. If you want to use `describe_battery()` you'll have to define it in your class and call `describe_battery()` for the `Battery`-object in it.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the `def __init__` typo, your error is a matter of object hierarchy, as you may have already figured.

## Explanation

`ElectricCar` receives a `Battery` object as a property, namely `battery_size`

```
class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery_size = Battery()
```

You put `describe_battery` as a property of the `Battery` class, so calling `my_tesla.describe_battery` won't ever work, because `my_tesla` is not an instance of `Battery`.

**Maintainability** is one of the main focal points of Pythonic ecosystems. With this in mind the below will solve your compilation problem, then improve how you are **interpolating strings**.

## A Maintainable Solution

There are many ways to make your code *work* - not all are best to maintain. An example of significant improvement with minor change to your code:

```
my_tesla.battery.describe()
```

"`describe` the `battery` within `my_tesla`"

This way clearly shows the hierarchy you're building, while being concise and readable. Plus the required changes are minimal.

Let's see how to do it here. In `ElectricCar.__init__`, change `battery_size` to `battery`

```
self.battery = Battery()
```

Within `Battery`, switch `describe_battery` to just `describe` - thus avoiding being redundant.

```
class Battery():
    ...
    def describe(self):
        ...
```

Now creating a Tesla and printing its battery goes like

```
my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2016)
my_tesla.battery.describe()
```

## Readability: String Interpolation

You have several places where you interpolate different strings here, and the way it's done could be more readable - canonical, even. Take `get_descriptive_name` as an example:

```
def get_descriptive_name(self):
    long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
    return long_name.title()
```

With the aid of `.format`, you could end with

```
def get_descriptive_name():
    return '{} {} {}'.format(self.year, self.make, self.model)
```

And my personal favorite: from python 3.6 onwards you could use f-strings, which are minimal and also  arguably more readable:

```
def get_descriptive_name():
    return f'{self.year} {self.make} {self.model}'
```

This could be ultimately applied to every interpolation you do here - `read_odometer`, the `describe` method, and `get_descriptive_name`. In terms of performance, all these are very similar, so this is ~60% a matter of preference.

Answer (score -1):

I'm quite new to python, but try this:

```
class Battery():
    def __init__(self, battery_size = 70):
        self.battery_size = battery_size
        self.describe2_battery()
    def describe2_battery(self):
        print("This car has a " + str(self.battery_size) + "-kWh battery." )

class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
    def describe_battery(self):
        Battery()



my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2016)
print(my_tesla.get_descriptive_name())
my_tesla.describe_battery()
```

The problem was, that you call a Function with `my_tesla.describe_battery` which didnt existed.

Comment: But this always creates a new `Battery`-object if `describe_battery` is called...

Comment: This is very far from optimal in performance (as @csabinho said, a new `Battery` is created every time) and the naming (`describe2_battery`)